# How to highlight a certain text on the contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript

The goal is to highlight certain words on the contenteditable div. Currently my approach is that using the regex to match the keywords that are inside `{ words }` or `[ words ]`.

```
const regexpSquareBracket = /\[[^\]]*\]/gm;
const regexCurlyBracket = /\{[^\}]*\}/gm;
  
const squareBracketMatches = text.match(regexpSquareBracket);
const curlyBracketMatches = text.match(regexCurlyBracket);
```

Above code working fine that correctly identifies this text.

```
Here is [the] sample [text] that matches the [certain words] in the given [text] and {highlight} the words in the text.
```

However the code I have for highlighting the text is not great because it only matches the single keyword rather than [multiple keywords compine].

I need you to give me the solution for how to improve below code that also matches the multiple keywords compine.

```js
var text = `Here is [the] sample [text] that matches the [certain words] in the given [text] and {highlight} the {words in the text}.`

// Find character index in a given list
const indexesOf = (arr, item) => 
  arr.reduce(
(acc, v, i) => (v === item && acc.push(i), acc),
  []);

const regexpSquareBracket = /\[[^\]]*\]/gm;
const regexCurlyBracket = /\{[^\}]*\}/gm;
  
const squareBracketMatches = text.match(regexpSquareBracket);
const curlyBracketMatches = text.match(regexCurlyBracket);

let splittedText = text.split(" ");

if (squareBracketMatches) {
  squareBracketMatches.forEach(function(match) {
var positions = indexesOf(splittedText, match)
positions.forEach(function(pos) {
  splittedText[pos] = `<span class="highlight-bracket">${splittedText[pos]}</span>`
})
  })
}

if (curlyBracketMatches) {
  curlyBracketMatches.forEach(function(match) {
var positions = indexesOf(splittedText, match)
positions.forEach(function(pos) {
  splittedText[pos] = `<span class="highlight-curly">${splittedText[pos]}</span>`
})
  })
}
console.log(splittedText.join(" "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var text = `Here is [the] sample [text] that matches the [certain words] in the given [text] and {highlight} the {words in the text}.`

const removeDuplicates = arr => [...new Set(arr)];

const regexpSquareBracket = /\[[^\]]*\]/gm;
const regexCurlyBracket = /\{[^\}]*\}/gm;

const squareBracketMatches = text.match(regexpSquareBracket);
const curlyBracketMatches = text.match(regexCurlyBracket);

for (const sq of removeDuplicates(squareBracketMatches)) 
  text = text.replaceAll(sq, `<span class="highlight-bracket">${sq}</span>`)

for (const curly of removeDuplicates(curlyBracketMatches))
  text = text.replaceAll(curly, `<span class="highlight-curly">${curly}</span>`)

console.log(text)
```

If the any of the brackets can be nested, sort the matches by longer string first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Doesn't match the repeatable words but it it closer.

Comment: Fixed, changed `replace` -> `replaceAll`